# How to make Maven copy resource file into WEB-INF/lib directory?

Tags: java, maven, war, newrelic

I'm using NewRelic for monitoring. I want Maven to package both *newrelic.jar* and *newrelic.yaml* files into my `WEB-INF/lib` inside the war file. With the *newrelic.jar* there is no problem since it's a simple dependency, but *newrelic.yaml* is a resource file. It resides in resources directory. I want Maven (war plugin) to copy it to `WEB-INF/lib` when packaging the war.

Thanks.

Alex

Comment: Shouldn't maven be putting it in `WEB-INF/classes` by default? This is where non-JAR resources need to go on the classpath

Comment: @mattb you're correct, that's the way it should be, but in new-relics docs they say both files have to be in the same dircetory [link to the docs](http://newrelic.com/docs/java/using-new-relic-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: that seems odd. It would be unusual for a class to look for resources specifically in `WEB-INF/lib` rather than to just load it from the classpath

Comment: @mattb I think it's because this jar is used for instrumentation ( -javaagent=newrelic.jar ) and I'm using Amazon elastic beanstalk so I have to package and deploy this monitoring war by myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While I agree with @matt b that this is odd, here's what you can do:

Try changing the configuration of the maven war plugin to include a webResource:

```
 <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>pathtoyaml</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.yaml</include>
          </includes>        
         <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
```

The directory is relative to the pom.xml. See [the plugin's documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

You can also specify most configuration for the New Relic agent including the location of the config file via flags passed to the java command.  In this case, it's something like:

-Dnewrelic.config.file=/etc/newrelic.yml

(ok, it's exactly like that, but you need to specify whatever path you need if it's not that.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should try adding .yaml file to newrelic.jar's resources, later
   you can access it via classpath.
2. Or try changing/overriding build.xml build target by adding something like < copy file=".yaml"
   todir="WEB-INF/lib" />

Try googling for more info on changing build.xml.

Comment: I'm not in control of newrelic.jar, it's a third-party. They look for the configuration file .yml in the same directory where the jar is. Another thing, I'm using Maven so there is not build.xml for me.