# Maven update jar before packaging in WAR

Tags: maven-war-plugin, truezip

I have a project where I am packaging a WAR using simple maven-war-plugin. Along with all other dependencies one of the dependency say 'abc.jar' which is getting packaged in war contains a default spring configurations which I would like to update with the custom one before packaging. I have maven profile configured to be activated if following build command applied;

```
mvn clean install -DframeworkPacakging=XYZ
```

I am trying to use 'truezip-maven-plugin' to overwrite my custom spring configurations inside in 'abc.jar' present in 'target/aretfacts-id/WEB-INF/lib' but when maven-war-plugin finishes I loose my changes because war plugin takes the file from dependency definition. How can I solve this issue and what are my options?

P.S. Distributing configuration is not desirable as this setup would be used for Embedded Jetty Server running within Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

1. to **prevent inclusion of the original jar file**, I would use go for approach suggested on: https://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg38537.html

   > Use `<scope>provided</scope>` for this dependency to keep it out of the
   >   lib directory.
2. to **include the repackaged one**, I'd follow suggestion from: [[How to make Maven copy resource file into WEB-INF/lib directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994088/how-to-make-maven-copy-resource-file-into-web-inf-lib-directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994088/how-to-make-maven-copy-resource-file-into-web-inf-lib-directory)

   > Try changing the configuration of the maven war plugin to include a webResource:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <webResources>
       <resource>
         <directory>pathtorepackagedjar</directory>
         <includes>
           <include>**/abc.jar</include>
         <includes>        
        <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
       </resource>
     </webResources>
   </configuration>
   ```